# Is there a way to add input field in nav element using React FluentUI (@fluentui/react)?

Tags: office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

The examples on [website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/nav) show many examples of navbars with links.
[Image of navbar demo as shown on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hszOh.png).

I want to implement a search bar inside the nav element [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbqj3.png). Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try with OnRenderLink or linkAs methods.

> onRenderLink:
> Used to customize how content inside the link tag is rendered
>
> linkAs: Render a custom link in place of
> the normal one. This replaces the entire button rather than simply
> button content
>
> Source: *INavProps interface* https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/nav

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @thePmSquare Happy to help!